# How to make onchange event in Polymer

Tags: javascript, polymer, document-ready

I'm getting this message **TypeError: document.addEventListener(...) is not a function**

```
(document.addEventListener('polymer-ready',function($){
 console.log('ready')
   // top link
   $.each(decodeURI(location.pathname).split('/'), function() {
      $("#self").html(this+'');
   });

   // browser default lang
   default_lang = navigator.language /* Mozilla */ || navigator.userLanguage /* IE */;

   // does URL contain lang=xx ?
   $.each(decodeURI(location.search.substr(1)).split('&'), function() {
     var s = this.split('=');
     if (s[0]=="lang") default_lang = s[1];
   });

   // toplevel = earth
   $("#earth").click(
     function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //location.href = "http://www.geonames.org";
     }
  );

  // entry point
  geo_click($("#earth"));
}))(jQuery);
```

Can someone tell me what is wrong with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem Solved!**

```
function geoready(){
console.log('ready');
// top link
$.each(decodeURI(location.pathname).split('/'), function() {
  $("#self").html(this+'');
});

// browser default lang
default_lang = navigator.language /* Mozilla */ || navigator.userLanguage /* IE */;

// does URL contain lang=xx ?
$.each(decodeURI(location.search.substr(1)).split('&'), function() {
    var s = this.split('=');
    if (s[0]=="lang") default_lang = s[1];
});

// toplevel = earth
$("#earth").click(
    function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //location.href = "http://www.geonames.org";
    }
);

// entry point
geo_click($("#earth"));
}
```

And I bind that in the Polymer constructor:

```
 <script>
    Polymer({
        is: "geo-dropdown",
        ready: geoready
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not valid you are treating the document.addEventListener as an IIFE which it is not. You are executing the (jQuery) at the wrong location.

Comment: So, how can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You pass jQuery into the immediate function not into the event listener.

```
(function ($) {
  document.addEventListener('polymer-ready', function () {
    console.log('ready')
    // top link
    $.each(decodeURI(location.pathname).split('/'), function () {
      $("#self").html(this + '');
    });

    // browser default lang
    var default_lang = navigator.language /* Mozilla */ || navigator.userLanguage /* IE */;

    // does URL contain lang=xx ?
    $.each(decodeURI(location.search.substr(1)).split('&'), function () {
      var s = this.split('=');
      if (s[0] == "lang") { default_lang = s[1] };
    });

    // toplevel = earth
    $("#earth").click(
      function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //location.href = "http://www.geonames.org";
      }
      );

    // entry point
    geo_click($("#earth"));
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Ty for the effort, but it didn't work :( I'm afraid that we can't do  document.addEventListener('polymer-ready',function() ...